# Keeping a mysql connection open untill the application is running

Tags: java, mysql

I have a java application which I have implemented its' database connection using singleton pattern. I only close the database connection when the main application is closed. Is it a good practice to keeping a database connection open like this? or what sort of problems might be occur?

Comment: I dont think it as a good practice.

Comment: Use connection pooling instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql Server usually closes the connection after a period of time(maybe default 8 hours, I'm not sure) and you must check whether the your connection is active. If the connection is closed, you must reconnect the sever.

Answer (score 3):

In general connection object should be closed as soon as you are finished with your interaction with DB.

Problem in keep opening is that .. connection object is a heavy object and in case of large enterprise application (it would not be the realistic case) it could make your application slow.

see link http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2ee/JDBC.htm#JDBC103 for optimizing JDBC connections, using connection pool etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to only use as much resources as you need at any one time. If your database has a limit on the number of connections it can have open at any one time then your application will be using up one of those whether it needs to or not.